# Growth of the truncation of the integral multiples of an irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, limits-and-convergence

Let $[a]$ denote the integral part of a real number $a$. 
Let $a$ be an irrational number and $b$ a real number greater than $1$. 
Consider the sequence $(b^n(na-[na]))$ with $n$ running on the positive integers.
I would like to know if this sequence diverges. In other words I want to know if the inverse of the sequence of truncations $(na-[na])$ growths slower than any exponentional sequence.

Comment: From [equidistribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) $na - [na] > \frac12$ infinitely frequently. Thus for any function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \infty$ the sequence $f(n) (na - [na])$ cannot remain bounded. But I think this is not exactly the question you asked in the final sentence. The final sentence seems to be asking about the $\liminf$ of $b^n (na - [na])$. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If, as Willie Wong suggests, the question is about the lim inf of $b^n (n a - \lfloor n a \rfloor)$, that is almost always $+\infty$ but generically $0$ (i.e. there is a dense 
$G_\delta$ set of $a$'s on which it is $0$).